# Checking two infinite sums are equal (Green's functions for heat eq)

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, greens-function

Given the heat equation on $x\in[0,1], t\geq 0$ with Dirichlet boundary condition 
$$\begin{cases}
u_t = u_{xx}\\ 
u(x,0) = g(x)\\
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0
\end{cases}$$

From Fourier series, we have the Green's function
$$G(x,y,t) = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n\pi x) \sin(n\pi y)$$

On the other hand, using fundemental solution $\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t} }e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}$, we have another Green's function 
$$\tilde G(x,y,t) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \Phi(x-(2n+y), t) - \Phi(x-(2n-y),t)$$

I think they can not be equal because where the factor of $t$ appears in the sum, however the solution $u(x,t)$ can be given by both Green's functions in the same format... 
$$u(x,t) = \int_0^1 g(y) \tilde G(x,y,t) dy = \int_0^1 g(y)  G(x,y,t) dy. $$

Here is the Poisson sum formula:

For a Schwartz function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, the summation 
$$F(x)=\sum_{n \mathop \in \mathbb{Z}} f \left(x+{n}\right)$$ defines a $1$-periodic function on the unit interval $[0,1)\ni x$, and its fourier coefficient is $\hat f(m)$, so

$$\sum_{n \mathop \in \mathbb{Z}} f \left(x+{n}\right) = \sum_{m \mathop \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat f \left({m}\right)e^{im2\pi x}$$
when $x=0$ we get
$$\sum_{n \mathop \in \mathbb{Z}} f \left({n}\right) = \sum_{m \mathop \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat f \left({m}\right)$$

Comment: I have not worked this out, but I am reasonably sure that the Poisson sum formula would be useful here.

Comment: Well, the Green's function is provably unique...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, but a comment too long to be edited in the comment section.

$$\begin{cases} 
u(x,0) = g(x)\\
u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0
\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad u(0,0)=g(0)=0\quad\text{and}\quad u(1,0)=g(1)=0$$

Expand the given function $g(x)$ in Fourier series on $0<x<1$ with $g(0)=g(1)=0$:

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\pi x)$$
So, the coefficients $a_n$ are known.

Solving $u_t=u_{xx}$ thanks to the method of separation of variables leads to the solution :
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\pi x)e^{-n^2\pi^2t}$$

Comment: Yes, and this corresponds to the Green's function $G$ defined above from Fourier transform, and $u(x,t) = \int_0^1 G(x,y,t)g(y) dy$ since your $a_n = 2\int_0^1 g(y)\sin(n\pi y) dy$.